# Redirect django URL to particular app

Tags: django

I am new to Django(1.7). As per my current configuration I am able to visit my app via url `"www.mydomainname.com/blog"`.

I want to redirect `"www.mydomain.com"` automatically to `"www.mydomainname.com/blog"`.

Please provide me suitable solutions.

My current **urls.py** has

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^blog/',include('blog.urls')),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='blog'), name='blog_view'),
)
```

**Update**: By default `RedirectView` return `301`. So recommend to include `permanent`

```
url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='blog', permanent=False), \
    name='blog_view'),
```

Comment: I recommend setting [`permanent`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.permanent) to `False` (it defaults to `True` until Django 1.9).

Answer (score 0):

Django 4.2: You can avoid editing views.py files by modifying urls.py in route directory as below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def redirect_view(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include("blog.urls")),
    path('', redirect_view, name='redirect_view'),
    re_path(r'^.+', redirect_view, name='redirect_view')
]
```